# Shiny apps folder on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server, ubuntu-server

After going through [this](http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/) and other shinyserver tutorial, I'm able to reach at this point.

[image]

And when I click the `sample_apps/hello/` example link, I reach here.

[image]

RStudio also works fine, but where do I put my shiny apps so that I can share them. The tutorial suggest to store apps at `/srv/shiny-server/`, however this folder cannot be found.

Any help, do I need to write some code in terminal to activate/make the folders visible?

[image]

I am using Putty to login to the server terminal.

Answer (score 1):

/srv/shiny-server/ is in the root of your filesystem.

If you want to serve shiny apps from your home directory you need to follow the instructions

From the [shiny server guide](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#host-per-user-application-directories):

```
run_as :HOME_USER:;

# Define the root location
location / {
  user_dirs;

  # Only allow members of the 'shinyUsers' group to host personal applications.
  members_of shinyUsers;
}
```